# Cell Structure of Three holed torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

How do I construct a torus as a cell structure?

Visually I do not think I quite see the construction. Furthermore, how do I construct a 3-holed torus, that is, a 3 genus surface as a cell structure?

Comment: Do you know how to glue a torus from a square? That might help

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes but I don't understand how to get to an identification square from adjunction spaces of cells

Answer (score 5):

If you glue a torus from a square, you can take the square to be the 2-cell, the edges to be its two 1-cells, and its vertices to be the one 0-cell.

A genus-3 surface is a connect sum of three tori.  You can make an identification diagram by cutting out a disk in a two-cell in each of the diagrams and pasting them together along the boundaries.  Then, to get a cell structure, you cut any 2d region that isn't just a disk.

[image: Connect sum of three tori]